Movie with a guy that has intercourse with a watermelon
This is a teen comedy movie I watched a long time ago. What I remember is:

a guy that will not leave his house (I think he was protesting or something)
he has a friend/neighbor that is obsessed with masturbation and one day he puts a watermelon in the sun and has intercourse with it
later that day the guy is eating a slice of watermelon and there is a hole in it
also later in the move he electrocutes himself with a DIY "love machine"

As I remember it, the protagonist (protesting guy) is wearing glasses and won't leave his house but will go out to the garden and he also meets a girl that he likes, who is blonde, and they have some chats over the fence.
The movie is in color, I watched it like ten years ago and if I remember correctly it was an American movie. It takes place in one of those neighborhoods that all the houses look alike and have a garden, kind of like the "Desperate Housewives" neighborhood.

Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

@Paulie_D Thanks for the comment, unfortunately it was a long time ago and I don't remember much of the movie, except of the weird guy. And google doesn't help a lot when you search for a guy and a watermelon...

How about Eight Days a Week (1997)?

Peter loves his next door neighbour Erica and, on the advice of his grandfather, decides to camp out on her front lawn for the entire summer, or until she agrees to go out with him. 
Peter's friend, Matt, thinks Peter should give up on women (like he has) and just have sex with fruit, and have a total devotion to masturbation.


You can watch the whole movie on youtube.

That's the one! Thank you!
